# Nesting gsub - bad practice?

Tags: r, gsub

```
x  <- "a_b_c"

x_new <- gsub("_[[:alnum:]]*$","",gsub("^[[:alnum:]]*_","",x))

x_new
```

Works perfectly fine, I was  just wondering whether this is bad programming style?

Thanks

Comment: Why not do it in one go (gsub call) if it's possible? It will be faster and probably cleaner. (For example, you can use backreferences `sub("^[[:alnum:]]*_(.*)_[[:alnum:]]*$", "\\1", x)`)

Comment: Please check if your code in the question should have underscores or not and edit accordingly

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the answers which were still helpful after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with one `gsub`.  Just use `|` to suggest `OR`

```
gsub("^[[:alnum:]]+|[[:alnum:]]+$", '', x)
```

Comment: To the negative voter, my solution was based on the OP's earlier post.  If it gets edited, I am not responsible.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what earlier post do you refer to?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I meant before the edit, it didn't have `_`.  I posted the solution only after checking the output from the OP's code.

Comment: hmm, strange, in the edit history it looks as if I added those underscores, but I didn't do that.. at least not consciously.. I thought I just formatted it as code. Rolled it back now

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Thanks, now I will go back to my earlier version